# How could I print multiple JTables on one page?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm working on java swing in which I have some JTables, I want to print some tables to be printed on one page because those are very small in height. is there any way to print those JTables on one page, one after the other ???

Comment: where is your tested codes ?

Comment: Please, explain you problem and show use what you have tried. See [ask]. Also, what  are you using to print ?

Comment: sorry for this im not on my machine so that's y i did not post my tested code. I just want to print multiple JTables on one page.

Comment: No need to tell this again, we can help you without any idea of how you are doing it at the beginning ... we are not going to do something from scratch (well I am not...)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Its kind of hard to tell what you mean without further explanation, but if you're trying to add JTables to JPanel or JFrame in vertical order, consider the  [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) manager, and possibly a [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) to make sure the tables fit on the screen.